# Magento attribute

Tags: magento

I am wondering if it is possible to have a "display name" AND an value in a magento attribute. At this stage as far as I can see the "display name" is the value that magento will use.

I am using e2mpro to list products from magento and want to be able to use an attribute for the store category in the list. With upto 300 numbers available I want to be able to associate a number with an easy to read display name. ie: 10020 -- Fiction: Scifi

Answer (score 2):

Depends of your setting how you want to display your attribute.

You can create a new attribute with your own preferences:

Log into admin => Catalog => Manage attributes => New attribute

"display name" in Magento you will find under Manage Label/options=> Manage Titles (Size, Color, etc.)

"value " under Properties (Catalog Input Type for Store Owner depends of your preferences you can select "Text field" "Text area" "Dropdown" etc....)

Answer (score 1):

Magento attributes by nature have a display name, a code, and a value.  The value could be a boolean (1/0, true/false, yes/no, etc), text, or a number.  I did a quick google search for Magento Attribute Value and [this page](http://www.sharpdotinc.com/mdost/2009/04/06/magento-getting-product-attributes-values-and-labels/) seems to have most of what you're looking for.  I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you'll have to create the attribute and next call it on your phtml file. Example

```
 $material = $product->getResource()
                     ->getAttribute('material')
                     ->getFrontend()
                     ->getValue($product);
 echo $material;

 $materialLabel = $product->getResource()
                     ->getAttribute('material_label')
                     ->getFrontend()
                     ->getLabel($product);
 echo $materialLabel;
```

You can also check this [post](http://www.magentodeveloper.ninja/how-to-display-custom-attributes-on-magento/) I wrote